# How do I return ALL columns in one table and just a few in another using join?

Tags: sql

I would rather not have to list all columns in tableA  The '*' works for one table, but I don't want to get back all columns in tableB from JOIN. Reason being, these records are being deleted, and I want to store data from tableA (only) as serialized xml for period of time.

Comment: Arguably, it is better practice to call out each column by name, instead of using *. Advantages of calling out columns by name can include decreased bandwidth usage, increased performance, and controlled maintenance costs (when columns are added to the underlying table).

Comment: you will likely have problems if you are trying to also use a group by statement with the select tableName.* method. Unless you have a really wide table with a lot of variables and it never matters if new variables are added (unlikely!), you should explicitly list the variables.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
select tableA.*, tableB.col1, tableB.col2, ...
```

Comment: @Martin She/he said she/he *doesn't* want all columns in tableB

Comment: @Null - Absolutely Correct - I must need another coffee.

Comment: Downvoted for encouraging the use of a SQL ANtipattern

Answer (score 3):

It is a poor practice to ever use select * or select table1.*. It is bad for maintenance and performance both. You should never do that in production code.

Just use the column names that you want.

Comment: That's good to know.  It would still be nice to know the newly added columns would be included automatically from TableA.  
If this wasn't a query for records to be deleted, I would definitely code all column names needed for query. In this case,  I need to serialize all data in case a restore needs to be done. Thanks,

Comment: yes but apparently this guy and me needs all columns

Comment: @FrederickG.Sandalo, so why is is hard to add them individually?

Comment: there are times when a table is around 20 columns and I need at least 2 tables.